# crop and align inserted BMP in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, crop, bmp

I want to crop and align the inserted BMP from the clipboard.
I'm trying for 2 days but still nothing workable...

```
procedure TForm1.act1Execute(Sender: TObject);
var
BMP : TBitmap;
begin
BMP := TBitmap.Create;
BMP.Assign(Clipboard);
BMP.SetSize(400,200);
Img1.picture.Graphic := BMP;
BMP.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.act1Update(Sender: TObject);
begin
(Sender as TAction).Enabled := Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_BITMAP);
end;

end.
```

Comment: Well, crop might be understandable, but align... Align to what ? Could you please edit your question and elaborate on this ?

Comment: Please indent your code. Please also explain what you are trying to do, and show the code of your best attempt.

Comment: sorry, I'm new on stackoverflow. I'm trying to paste a image/BMP from the clipboard. The problem is that the image I want to paste doensn't fit. So, besides resizing it the image must be cropped in it's width.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you right, you need to center the bitmap in the Image control?

It's simple - set the `Img1.Center := True`

To crop the bitmap you need code like this:

```
    procedure CropBitmap(Bmp: TBitmap; const CropRect: TRect);
    var
      CropBmp: TBitmap;
    begin
      CropBmp := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        CropBmp.Width := CropRect.Right - CropRect.Left;
        CropBmp.Height := CropRect.Bottom - CropRect.Top;
        CropBmp.Canvas.CopyRect(
          Rect(0, 0, CropBmp.Width, CropBmp.Height),
          Bmp.Canvas,
          CropRect
        );
        Bmp.Assign(CropBmp);
      finally
        CropBmp.Free;
      end;
    end;
```