# How do I get maximum centered rectangular area of Image in firemonkey c++

Tags: c++, firemonkey

I'm trying to crop an image in a rectangular area, to fill a circle with it, but I cannot find any way to do that. Tt says that the result of my code is not correct and the image is not well placed. I don't know what is wrong in my code.

I saw some examples , but they are not working for me.

Here are the sites I visited:

[crop and align inserted BMP in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966034/crop-and-align-inserted-bmp-in-delphi)

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22142653/Crop-Bitmap-Image1.html

[Delphi - how do I crop a bitmap "in place"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183524/delphi-how-do-i-crop-a-bitmap-in-place)

[How to crop an FMX TBitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31159795/how-to-crop-an-fmx-tbitmap)

Note: the code should be wrote in FMX whit C++, it should run in all platforms.
The TCircle have the WrapMode assign to TileStrech.

```
    void __fastcall TForm9::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
    {
       int X , Y , W , H;

       if(Image1->Bitmap->Width >= Image1->Bitmap->Height)
       {
          H = Image1->Bitmap->Height;
          X = (Image1->Bitmap->Width - Image1->Bitmap->Height) / 2;
          Y = 0;
          W = H;
       }
       else
       {
          W = Image1->Bitmap->Width;
          X = 0;
          Y = (Image1->Bitmap->Width - Image1->Bitmap->Height) / 2;
          H = W;
       }

       TRect rect(X, Y, W, H);
       TBitmap * bm = new TBitmap(W,H);
       bm->CopyFromBitmap(Image1->Bitmap ,rect ,X,Y);

       Circle1->Fill->Bitmap->Bitmap->Assign(bm);

       Image2->Bitmap->Assign(bm);
       delete bm;
    }
```

The result of this code is:
    [The bitmap is not well placed in a Circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdel1.png)

My objetive is get an crop image like this :
[image croped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awn6G.jpg)

---

#### Solved

I have one solution for this problem

```
int CropBitmap(TBitmap* in, TBitmap* out)
{
  if (!in or !out)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  TBitmap * bm = new TBitmap();

  int origH = in->Height;
  int origW = in->Width;
  TRect rect;
  int defH, defW;
  if (origH > origW)
  {
    bm->Height = origW;
    bm->Width = origW;

    int factor = (origH - origW) / 2;
    rect.Top = factor;
    rect.Left = 0;
    rect.Right = origW;
    rect.Bottom = factor + origW;

    bm->CopyFromBitmap(in, rect, 0, 0);
  }
  else if (origW > origH)
  {
    bm->Height = origH;
    bm->Width = origH;

    int factor = (origW - origH) / 2;
    rect.Top = 0;
    rect.Left = factor;
    rect.Right = factor + origH;
    rect.Bottom = origH;

    bm->CopyFromBitmap(in, rect, 0, 0);
  }
  else
  {
    bm->Assign(in);
  }

  out->Assign(bm);
  delete bm;
  return 0;
}
```

It run well for me.

Comment: debug what you're doing with the coordinates... you'll probably want to center it, but as there are different scaling options (crop, scale-to-fit, ...) specify what is your intended outcome. and what is the middle picturebox?

Comment: in fact, I would like crop the maximum rectangle placed at center. so if the Width is greater than Height the side of the rectangle will be the Width, otherwise the Height. I've edit the question and added an goal image! thanks you por answer